# how to apply JavaScript replace() Method 2 time in a page

Tags: javascript

JavaScript replace() Method

Hello **username**!Don’t forget me this weekend!**Username**.

When i use this

```
str.replace("username", "Username");
```

but it's replace only first occurance i have to perform replace all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regex with the global flag set:

```
str.replace(/username/g, 'Username')
```

Answer (score 2):

Usa a global regular expression. The `g` modifier makes it search the entire string.

```
str.replace(/username/g, "Username");
```

You could also surround it with word boundaries if needed to avoid substring matches.

```
str.replace(/\busername\b/g, "Username");
```